# Using a Big Cell in TableView instead of a ScrollView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm making an app that requires I use multiple custom UIControls in some sort of scrolling view. The *control's* size depends on the auto layout constraints placed on it. Unfortunately, `ScrollView` doesn't interact well with AutoLayout and this particular UIControl's sizing.

One potential solution would be to place these controls in a very tall `UITableView` cell and simply use that cell as a sort of `ScrollView`.

Besides accessibility, are there any problems with doing this?

I'm new to this so any help is appreciated,

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: You mean you want many rows and each row have many column that you can swipe on?

Comment: No, just one large row